# Flag belongs-on-s* questions as requiring moderator attention?

Tags: support, moderation

Is it OK to flag belongs-on-s* questions as requiring moderator attention?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have the ability to vote yourself, I don't see any problem with flagging it for moderator attention. It may be the fastest way to get it moved. If the mod doesn't think it needs to be moved, he'll just ignore your flag.

Comment: Is it possible that there are un-documented rep powers. Like at 100,000 your vote closes instantly like Moderators? And people just haven't gotten to it yet?

Comment: @Chacha, possible but very doubtful.

Comment: Very doubtful.

Answer (score 1):

There was one question were I flagged for moderator attention, *after* voting to close.

I only did this, because I was looking through old questions, and it was unlikely anyone else would find it.

Comment: I did it 'cause it was taking too long and i wanted to do something with it on meta.

Comment: I think the one I was talking about went to SU or SF.